# How to assign values from two matrices to each other in sequence?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to assign a value from the second matrix to the values in the first lubricator according to the example.
First, I go through the last row in the matrix b and assign the values from the matrix d to it gradually. Then I move one line higher in the matrix b and the next position in the matrix d and I also assign successively. And so I proceed to the end of the matrix

Example

import numpy as np

```
b=np.array([13,14,15,16,17],
           [22,23,24,25,26],
           [31,32,33,34,35])

d=np.array[100,200,300,400,500,600,700]
```

required output

```
31 100
32 200
33 300
34 400
35 500
22 200
23 300
24 400
25 500
26 600
13 300
14 400 
15 500 
16 600
17 700
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I made minor fixes in syntax.
The -(negative) indexing will be useful.
you need to iterate -1,-2... rows on b. -1 = last row.
and use row id to get offset in d.

```
import numpy as np
b=np.array([[13,14,15,16,17],
           [22,23,24,25,26],
           [31,32,33,34,35]])

d=np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700])

for i in range(1, 1+len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[-i])):
        print(b[-i][j], d[i+j-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that you can reorder the rows of `b` and stack them in sequence horizontally.
Then create a matrix from the array `d` by taking the element from i to i + len(row(b)), where i start from 0 and shift after each epoch, then stack the rows in sequence horizontally.
Finally you can zip the two arrays to obtain the desired result

```
b=np.array([[13,14,15,16,17],
           [22,23,24,25,26],
           [31,32,33,34,35]])

d=np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700])

val1 = np.hstack(b[::-1])
val2 = np.hstack([d[i:i+b.shape[1]] for i in range(b.shape[0])])
res = zip(val1, val2)
for i, j in res:
    print(i, j)
```

output:

```
31 100
32 200
33 300
34 400
35 500
22 200
23 300
24 400
25 500
26 600
13 300
14 400
15 500
16 600
17 700
```

Answer (score 0):

If your indexing from `d` array is predicated by `a` array, you can try something like:

```
>>> order = b[::-1]
>>> idx = (order % 10) - 1
>>> np.stack([order.ravel(), d[idx].ravel()]).T

array([[ 31, 100],
       [ 32, 200],
       [ 33, 300],
       [ 34, 400],
       [ 35, 500],
       [ 22, 200],
       [ 23, 300],
       [ 24, 400],
       [ 25, 500],
       [ 26, 600],
       [ 13, 300],
       [ 14, 400],
       [ 15, 500],
       [ 16, 600],
       [ 17, 700]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view `d` as the matrix that corresponds to the flipped `b`:

```
v = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(d, shape=b.shape, strides=d.strides * 2)
```

Now you can stack the two together:

```
result = np.ravel((b[::-1].ravel(), v.ravel()), axis=-1)
```